# Truncate or Drop and Create Table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, truncate

I have this table in a SQL Server 2008 R2 instance which I have a scheduled process that runs nightly against it. The table can have upward to 500K records in it at any one time. After processing this table I need to remove all rows from it so I am wondering which of the following methods would produce the least overhead (ie Excessive Transaction Log entries):

1. Truncate Table
2. Drop and recreate the table

Deleting the contents of the table is out due to time and extra Transaction log entries it makes.

The consensus seems to be Truncation, Thanks everyone!

Comment: [Some comparisons between amount of logging here](http://dba.stackexchange.com/a/7685/3690). `TRUNCATE` has slightly less logging than `DROP` as dropping also causes the associated rows for that object to be deleted from the system tables (which is also logged)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Truncating the table does not leave row-by-row entries in the transaction log - so neither solution will clutter up your logs too much. If it were me, I'd truncate over having to drop and create each time.

Answer (score 17):

`TRUNCATE TABLE` is your best bet. From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260621%28v=sql.80%29.aspx):

> Removes all rows from a table without logging the individual row
>   deletes.

So that means it won't bloat your transaction log. Dropping and creating the table not only requires more complex SQL, but also additional permissions. Any settings attached to the table (triggers, `GRANT` or `DENY`, etc.) will also have to be re-built.

Answer (score 6):

I would go for TRUNCATE TABLE. You can potentially have overheads when indexes, triggers, etc get dropped. Plus you will lose permissions which will also have to be re-created along with any other required objects required for that table.

Also on [DROP TABLE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173790.aspx) in MDSN below it mentions a little gotcha if you execute DROP and CREATE TABLE in the same batch

> DROP TABLE and CREATE TABLE should not be executed on the same table
>   in the same batch. Otherwise an unexpected error may occur.

Answer (score 3):

Dropping the table will destroy any associated objects (indexes, triggers) and may make procedures or views invalid. I would go with truncate, since it won't blow up your log and causes none of the possible issues a drop and create does.

Comment: Thanks, there aren't any associated indexes or triggers, I am just worried about the transaction log growing too big.

Comment: I learned this the hard way when I started adding extended properties to my tables, and because my t-sql scripts used drop-and-create, I had to re-enter the extended properties and change the scripts to truncate. No lost extended properties after that.